# Google Sites: Markdown support?

Tags: google-workspace, markdown, google-classic-sites

My organization is interested in migrating our local Wiki from the office into Google Sites. I see that Google Sites supports some sort of Wiki interface, but I don't really like the GUI editor. Is it possible to use Markdown syntax instead?

This is a Unix-heavy shop, with many Unix-heads and engineers. Many of us prefer the code-friendly wiki syntax provided by Markdown.

Comment: Now that would be truly awesome ... Great question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've hunted around the interwebs for just this solution, and ***HIGHLY*** recommend using [Markdown Here](http://markdown-here.com/).  It is a browser extension for Chrome, Firefox and Safari that lets one toggle back-and-forth between Markdown and HTML.  It's original use-case is for in composing e-mail, but it ["works great"](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Compatibility) in Google Sites.  Also, it supports TeX math formula, which for researchers, I would imagine could be quite useful.

FWIW, I started down the path of using the Markdown Site Editor suggested by @dnozay, but it seemed overly complicated for a few reasons:

- It forces each site maintainer to add it for Markdown functionality.
- It has the potential to break as Google's tools change, and someone then has to get the latest version (possibly for each site).
- Some environments have scripting and/or google app engine hobbled for security/policy/etc. reasons
- Philosophically, it makes Google Sites try to be something it's not.

Using Markdown Here means

- No additional code needs to be added to each google site.
- It is a well maintained tool that is installed once in a browser and useful is in many places (e-mail, sites, blogger, facebook, tumblr, tinymce, etc.)
- The onus of responsibility is on the individual who wants to use Markdown (and TeX).
- It let's Sites be Sites, and Markdown writers be Markdown writers.

Comment: And did I mention that it's [open source](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/ "GitHub")?

Comment: I was little overzealous, perhaps.  :/  It seems saving a page in sites may strip out the html markers that let you toggle back-and-forth to Markdown with MDH.  I still recommend it for other purposes.

Comment: THIS IS AMAZING!

Comment: Actually does work in sites, including after you've saved, but if you add *any* html manually using the WYSIWYG editor, you can no longer transform that particular page back to Markdown.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for following up. Don't add any additional html? Unfortunately, I'm sorry. I'm afraid i can't do that, @Dave.

Comment: Does it still work in the new Google Sites? Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! Works great in gmail and other rich text editor locations! Super cool. Just remember to restart chrome with `chrome://restart` in the search bar before using it after installing the extension. See my note here: https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/issues/504#issuecomment-528703850.

Comment: @GuidoWalterPettinari, it *sort of* works in the new Google Sites. It's very buggy though, due to the new Google Sites interface which automatically converts dashes to bullets, for instance. See my bug report here: https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/issues/574.

Comment: I tried it 2022-01-04. It makes google sites crash ( a lot ). It is unusable. I blame google-sites. It is not the best tool.

Answer (score 4):

While I'm impressed that your organization would rather use Markdown than a WYSIWYG editor, I'm afraid that Google sites does not currently support Markdown syntax.  You could write the text in Markdown locally using an editor like Textmate, and use a bundle or a script to convert that to HTML, and then paste the HTML into your site (Google Sites will let you add raw HTML to your sites -- inside certain form elements) but that feels like overkill.

Comment: This is a National Lab, and nearly everyone here uses Unix, writes code or is very technical. I'm promoting my bias for a code-friendly Wiki ;)

Comment: It would work for the first version, but how do you get back markdown from HTML ? Unless you keep 2 versions - local and online HTML, not very practical.

Comment: @Stefan -- indeed!  Love that bias.  
@Miro -- indeed!  Not very practical.

Comment: If you're willing to do some programming, you could perhaps integrate your Google Site with Google Drive. Create a folder in Google Drive that is designated as Site content, and give Site editors access to the folder. Then write a Google Apps script that imports the folder's contents to the Site (using the Sites API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol#UpdatingContent), while converting it from Markdown to HTML. This would allow editors to edit content locally (via Google Drive sync), with any text editor they want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://sites.google.com/site/gashackja/markdownsiteeditor

--

And you can install it for your own use:

1. get a [copy of `Markdown Site Editor`](https://script.google.com/d/1v3NUP-HhVKl0-8Tpy2VJZ4tRH5p2tX7db3tHKGI_YYLrnlEMt5aSmHuI/edit?usp=sharing).

   [image: making a copy of Markdown Site Editor]
2. adding the libraries.

   [image: adding the library]
3. get the `Showdown library` by looking it up (ID: `M6WggW1B7uEj1Nu0p7S6Pf-Mffa6w-w2J`)

   [image: adding showdown library]
4. make sure to change the identifier to `Showdown` (instead of `GASShowdown`)
5. get the `Bootstrap library` (ID: `MKvZneZcEte-sNijM1TaY_eMffa6w-w2J`)
6. make sure the identifier is `Bootstrap` (instead of `GASBootstrap`)
7. save everything
8. create a version (`File` > `Manage versions`)
9. deploy as a web app (`Publish` > `Deploy as a web app...`)

Comment: Thank you! That looks interesting. I followed instructions 1-9 above, but I am not sure how to make use of this script. How would I use this with Google Sites? Should I expect to see something under Google Apps Scripts?

Comment: I don't like that these scripts contain references to some dropbox user files. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth checking out these:

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/27175

> Fluid app userscript, build to support Markdown in Highrise and Basecamp

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/2531

> Based on js-markdown and it enables you to convert Markdown formatted text to HTML in one single click.